# wordpress facebook plugin to like facebook page not current page

Tags: facebook, wordpress

was hoping you could help me out.

I am using the 'facebook plugin' on a wordpress site. It places a 'like' button on every page which likes the current page. Instead, I want it to 'like' my facebook page (i.e all the 'like' buttons should have a custom, static "href"). Is there a way to do this using the plugin?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your after this:

Where FACEBOOKPAGENAMEHERE is put you facebook page name :)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=270759766403290";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/FACEBOOKPAGENAMEHERE" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
```